# Can't run any xcode project in Mac

Tags: xcode, macos

I'm getting this error while running any xcode project.

> Lost connection to “My Mac”. Restore the connection to “My Mac” and run “Project Name” again, or if “Project Name” is still running, you can attach to it by selecting Debug > Attach to Process > “Project Name”.

I've seen similar questions but couldn't extract an answer from them. Has anyone encountered this issue recently?

Here is the error from Xcode.

[image]

Appreciate your help!

Comment: try cmd+shift+k and then cmd+R

Comment: @MdRashedPervez Same error.

Comment: @KarimMasoud Add links to the similar questions so people don't give you suggestions that you already tried.

Comment: Have you figured out why?

Comment: @hyouuu Not yet.